# How can I create n numbers of instances for a class?

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to write a code whereby I can set a variable, say n, to create n numbers of instances for that particular class. The instances have to be named 'Node_1', 'Node_2'...'Node_n'. I've tried to do this in several ways using the for loop, however I always get the error: 'Can't assign to operator.'

My latest effort is as follows:

```
class C():
    pass
for count in range(1,3):
    "node"+str(count)=locals()["C"]()

print(node)
```

I understand that the `"node" + str(count)` is not possible, but I don't see how I can solve this issue.

Any help on the matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put them in a list, not separate variables.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a dictionary? "variable variables" aren't a good idea

Comment: Do you _need_ to start counting at `1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* do what you're trying to do, but it's a really bad idea. You should either use a `list` or a `dict`; since you seem to want the names to be `nodeX`, and starting from `1`, you should use a `dict`.

```
nodes = {'node{}'.format(x): C() for x in range(1, 3)}
```

Depending on what you're doing, you could also use a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

nodes = defaultdict(C)

print(nodes['node1'])

nodes['node2'].method()

print(nodes['anything-can-go-here'])
```

Once you're doing that though, there's no need for the `'node'` prefix.

Comment: My guess is that the `'node'` prefix is merely an artifact of [problem Y](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A `list` is probably the best option, as it would turn something like `nodes['node2']` into `nodes[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

The best pattern for creating several similar objects is a `list` comprehension:

```
class C():
    pass

nodes = [C() for i in range(3)]
```

This leaves you with three objects of class `C`, stored in a `list` called `nodes`. Access each object in the normal way, with indexing (e.g. `nodes[0]`).

Comment: Yes! Ditch the redundant variables and embrace the zero-based indexing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign a value to a string. You can write `Node_1 = C()`, but `"Node_1" = C()` is meaningless, as `"Node_1"` is a string literal, not an identifier.

It's a little sketchy, but you can use the `locals()` dictionary to access the identifiers by name:

```
for count in range(1, 3):
    locals()["node" + str(count)] = C()
```

...and, having done that, you can then use `node1` and `node2` as if they were defined explicitly in your code.

Typically, however, it's preferable to not access your locals this way, rather you should probably be using a separate dictionary of your own creation that stands on its own and contains the values there:

```
nodes = {}
for count in range(1, 3):
    nodes[count] = C()
```

... and the values can then be accessed like so: `nodes[1]`, `nodes[2]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do, to keep a registry of all the instances of a class:

```
class C(object):
    instances = {}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(C, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        instance_name = 'node_{}'.format(len(cls.instances))
        cls.instances[instance_name] = instance
        return instance


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(3):
        C()

    print C.instances
```

OrderedDict([('node_0', <**main**.C object at 0x10c3fe8d0>), ('node_1', <**main**.C object at 0x10c4cb610>), ('node_2', <**main**.C object at 0x10c4e04d0>)])

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of creating those instances in a tidy way. What if we want to create five of those objects? 50? 500?

Comment: True, but a simple for loop will creates these n objects, and the class will "name" each instance, which will be accessible via C.instances[node_x]